# Auto-generate alphanumeric unique Id with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Need to create employee record based on branch.

I have a scenario, where if branch combo box value is selected xyz branch then

ID starts with XYZ-0001

If combo box value is selected abc branch then

ID starts with ABC-0001 and then so on

Please suggest any idea on how to create this format.

Comment: filter all employees ID starting with branch_code, order by desc, take first record. then split by '-', get ID number and save new employee as concat branch_code & (last_id + 1)

Comment: if you want to generate unique user IDs: <locationIdentifier>-<Guid> maybe?

Comment: Just a a general comment, you should not try to solve this in C#, i have have a similar situation  where I had to get a unique id for a multi user application, it all went fine until 2 users did the same thing at the same time (given enough time this will happen) and the keys generated were not unique.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise against storing your employee ID as a column in your database. Its just bad form, specifically Bad Normal Form.

I would advise you to store the "employee ID" in two separate columns, of `Branch` and `BranchEmployeeId`.

This will allow you to much more quickly figure out the next ID in a sequence, and you should be able to ask questions like "how many employees are their in branch XYZ" using the database indices.

However I would warn you that overall you need to consider if the employee ID form really makes sense. Do employees ever move branch? Can an employee work at multiple branches?

Answer (score -1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Creating a sequence in SQL server 1 for each branch.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx

Use the next value to the get the next sequence number

then Use C# to create the ID based on the return value (or if you fancy SQL use SQL).

Then format the value you get like this:

```
value = 123;
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00000"));
 Console.WriteLine(combo.SelectedItem.ToString()+ "-" + String.Format("{0:00000}", value));
 // Displays ABC-00123
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of saving ID as 'XYZ-0001', I would suggest saving the ID as some unique value.

**BranchTable**

1. ID (unique)
2. Name
3. Code(varchar(3) : 3 letter code for the branch eg:XYZ)
4. ...

**EmployeeTable**

1. ID (unique)
2. Number (int: count()+1 of employees in a branch)
3. BranchID (foreign key)

And `employeenumber` as `count()+1` of number of employees in a branch while displaying you could show `'BranchCode'-'EmployeeNumber'` as employeecode.

`Branch + "-" + String.Format("{0:D4}", employeenumber);`

Answer (score -2):

Best way is, get the last updated is from the Db

Step 1: 
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM YourTable;
Step 2: 
Increment the ID value by 1 or so and append it with the combobox value....

Comment: this would fail in a multi user enviroment